# Adding line wrap to XML with XMLStreamWriter

Tags: xml, vb.net

I've been working on a function inside a larger application to export data from objects in memory, to an XML file. The goal being to then read that data back into memory at later time(s) rather than having to rebuild it by querying the database.

I've been able to generate the XML document with an `XmlWriter`, but I'm not in love with the formatting of said document. There are no new line characters, the XML is just one continuous string.

Other than using a regular `StreamWriter` to add a new line at the end of each element I haven't been able to see a way to get the XML to include line breaks, & the proper indenting of each line, so it is human read-able.

As an example I get this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Library><Database>hasp</Database><Table><Name>FLOW_ACT_LOG$</Name><Desc /><Column><Name /><DB_Name>APPL_INFO</DB_Name><Type /><Column><Name /><DB_Name>T_STAMP</DB_Name>
```

When I should get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Library>
    <Database>hasp</Database>
        <Table>
            <Name>FLOW_ACT_LOG$</Name>
            <Desc />
                <Column>
                    <Name />
                    <DB_Name>APPL_INFO</DB_Name>
                    <Type />
                <Column>
                    <Name />
                    <DB_Name>T_STAMP</DB_Name>
```

For reference my XML generation code is below:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Converts the table library to an XML file for storage and later retrieval
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Mwin">The MainWin instance, which holds the DataStore with
''' the library</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub SaveLibrary(ByVal Mwin As MainWin)
    '
    Dim lw As System.Xml.XmlWriter = Nothing
    Dim lwset As System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings = New Xml.XmlWriterSettings
    Dim floc As String = ""
    Dim path As String = Mwin.DS.StorStr & "Connection Libraries\" & _
             Mwin.ODBCCons.Text & " Library.xml"

    'Setup the writer settings
    Try
        lwset.Indent = True
        lwset.CloseOutput = True
        lwset.WriteEndDocumentOnClose = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrBox("Failed to correctly configure the XML writer. The application " & _
        "will continue, but the XML file will not be as orderly. Error Details: " & _
        ex.Message, "ok", Mwin)
    End Try

    'Check if the file exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(path) Then
        Try
            'Delete the existing file
            System.IO.File.Delete(path)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrBox("Failed to clear the current information from the library file." _
            & " Please reattempt the save. If that fails contact the administrator" _
            & " for this tool with the following error details: " & ex.Message, _
            "ok", Mwin)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If

    'In all cases we now start writing the XML file
    Try
        floc = "writing the top level node of the XML document"
        'Start writing to a new version of the file
        lw = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(path)
        lw.WriteStartDocument()
        lw.WriteStartElement("Library")
        lw.WriteElementString("Database", Mwin.ODBCCons.Text)

        'Iterate through the schemas
        For Each s As SchObj In Mwin.DS.TblLib
            floc = "writing the schema level elements for the schema " & s.Name

            'Iterate through the tables
            For Each t As TblObj In s.Tables
                floc = "writing the table level elements for the table " & t.Name
                lw.WriteStartElement("Table")
                lw.WriteElementString("Name", t.Name)
                lw.WriteElementString("Desc", t.Desc)

                'iterate through the columns
                For Each c As ColObj In t.Cols
                    floc = "writing the column details for " & c.Name & " on table" _
                    & " " & t.Name
                    lw.WriteStartElement("Column")
                    lw.WriteElementString("Name", c.Name)
                    lw.WriteElementString("DB_Name", c.DbName)
                    lw.WriteElementString("Type", c.DType)
                Next

                'Relationships
                For Each r As RelObj In t.Rels
                    floc = "writing the relationship details for " & r.TableA & "-" _
                    & r.TableB & " on table " & t.Name
                    lw.WriteStartElement(r.TableB)
                    lw.WriteElementString("Key1", r.Key1)
                    lw.WriteElementString("Key2", r.Key2)
                    lw.WriteElementString("Key3", r.Key3)
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrBox("An error was encountered while " & floc & ". Any information that " _
        & "had been output prior to this point will be saved, but the entirety of " _
        & "the table library may not be in the resultant XML file. Use caution " & _
        "when using this table library in the future." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
        "This error does NOT impact the in-memory table library, and as such" & _
        " the application should continue to operate successfully." & Chr(10) & _
        Chr(10) & "Error Details: " & ex.Message, "ok", Mwin)
    End Try

    'Close the file (should implicitly save)
    Try
        lw.Close()
        lwset = Nothing
        lw = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrBox("Encountered an error while closing the library's save file. The " & _
        "application can continue to operate with the in-memory library, but there " _
        & "may be issues when the library is " _
               & "reloaded in the future. Error Details: " & ex.Message, "ok", Mwin)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the `XmlWriterSettings` object and set its properties correctly:

```vb
Dim lwset As System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings = New Xml.XmlWriterSettings
' ...
lwset.Indent = True
lwset.CloseOutput = True
lwset.WriteEndDocumentOnClose = True
```

But then you never actually use that object anywhere.  If you passed that settings object as an argument to the `XmlWriter.Create` method, then it would use those settings to determine how it formats the output:

```vb
lw = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(path, lwset)
```

I tested it, and once I actually passed the settings object to the `Create` method, it did format the XML in the desired way.

For what it's worth, you may want to look into using one of the existing XML serializer tools such as the `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer` which do much of this work for you.  Also, you may want to consider using the `Using` keyword for the writer rather than calling the `Close` method manually.